# Flutter + Firebase: how to send email verification

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I tried to read online and can't find an answer on how to use the `sendSignInLinkToEmail()`

In particular I'm interested in what actionCodeSettings is and what value it should have. Ty in advance.

```
Future verificationEmail(email) async {
  try { 
     FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
                                      email: email,
                                      actionCodeSettings: null
      } catch (err) { 
          print(err);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[NEW FORMAT]

```
_firebaseAuthInstance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
    email: "rocky_balboa@example.com,
    actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
        url: "https://example.page.link/cYk9",
        androidPackageName: "com.example.app",
        iOSBundleId: "com.example.app",
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        androidMinimumVersion: "16",
        androidInstallApp: true),
  );
```

[DEPRECATED] (yeah, already...)

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
      email: "example@example.com",
      actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
        url: "https://example.web.app",
        android: {
          'packageName': "com.example.example",
          'installApp': true,
          'minimumVersion': '12'
        },
        iOS: {
          'bundleId': "com.example.example",
        },
        handleCodeInApp: true,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like email link sign-in is not too well documented yet in the brand new [Flutter/Firebase documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage).

In cases like that I recommend looking at the equivalent Firebase documentation for Android. In this case the documentation on [sending an authentication link to the user's email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address) seems to have what you need. You'll need to create an [`ActionCodeSettings` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/ActionCodeSettings-class.html) and pass that into the call to `sendSignInLinkToEmail`.

Comment: Agreed, the documentation is lacking usage for passwordless authentication :/